A quotation by Jean Bernard
Jean Bernard [1907-2006] was a famous French medical doctor, also a University Professor and a researcher. He was a member of the Académie Française and wrote several books, both on scientific topics as well as on the sociology of medical practice.
My Question. I am looking for a rather well-known quotation of JB about scientific research. If I remember correctly, it goes essentially as follows:
If you do something new in research, people around you, foes and friends, will say "it's wrong." When you have proven that what you have done is correct, the same people would say "fine, it is true, but the result is not yours". Once people realized that what you have done is correct and indeed to be attributed to you, the matters do not improve because you will be told, "fine, it's true, it's yours but it is not interesting."
It seems to me that the ordeal goes on and on, but I do not know in which text or interview Jean Bernard actually said this. I would be very grateful for some hint or indication about the source of the above quotation.

Why do you think the quotation is "well-known" if you can't find any mention of it on the Internet?

I wrote "well-known" because I met several people who quoted these sentences. However, none of these persons were able to provide me with a clearcut reference. Looking on the internet was my first move, but with respect to these particular sentences, it was unsuccessful.
